# Method Name Expected Discord Bot

Tags: c#, discord

When I attempt to run this extremely simple command to get my discord bot [see below] I get this error: `CS0149  C# Method name expected`
I believe it's referring to the `discord` in `discord.connect`. If anyone knows how to fix this problem it would be greatly appreciated.

**Command:**

```
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ImBotOdd
{
    class MyBot
    {
        DiscordClient discord;

        public MyBot()
        {
            discord = new DiscordClient(x =>
            {
                x.LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info;
                x.LogHandler = Log;
            });

            discord.ExecuteAndWait(async () =>
            {
                await discord.Connect("token", TokenType.Bot)("DONT COPY MY TOKEN");


        });
        }

        private void Log(object sender, LogMessageEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested out this code and it was working fine. Which version of discord.net are you using? What .NET framework version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you fixed it but it seems like you have not added

"Using Discord;"

Otherwise it should work (Tested on 0.9)